# Bug in adding constraints for view in cell

Tags: constraints, swift3

I am trying to adding constraints for one view in cell.
This is my code :

```
let labelView = UIView()
let labelItem = UILabel()

labelItem.text = menuList[indexPath.row-1]
labelItem.textColor = UIColor.white
labelView.addSubview(labelItem)

cell.addSubview(labelView)
labelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: wCell).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
```

But, it error "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". Can you help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the method of adding constraints programatically has been changed in Swift 3, see more information here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html